Applications of line and surface integrals where the underlying space is not the physical space
Line and surface integrals in vector calculus are often motivated by the following physical examples: the work along a path in a force field (line integrals) and the flux of an extensive quantity through a surface (surface integrals). In these and all other examples I've seen, the underlying space is interpreted as the 3D (or 2D) physical space.
I'm looking for examples from applied areas where line and surface integrals appear, yet the underlying space is not the physical 3D space but some other "state space" (like the space of energy, entropy, temperature values, etc.).
The applied area could still be physics, but others (chemistry, biology, statistics, computer science, economics, etc.) would be even more interesting.
In case the question is not precise enough: I'm looking for examples from applied areas where an integral of a differential $k$-form over a $k$-dim submanifold of some ambient manifold $M$ appears ($k<\dim M$), and $M$ is not interpreted as our physical space or space-time.
I don't necessarily expect the examples to be simple enough to be fully discussed in an introductory vector calculus course.
A related question:
Applications of Vector Calculus to Economics/Finance

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure%E2%80%93volume_diagram

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature%E2%80%93entropy_diagram

Sorry I don't have time to write up a full answer, but maybe the links above can inspire an answer along these lines.

@StevenGubkin thanks! Now that you mentioned it, I realise that I had seen one forms in thermodynamics but forgotten about it.

An example:
In a 2D crystal lattice, the Brillouin zone is topologically a torus, denoted by $\mathbb{T}^2$, as the momenta $k_x$ and $k_y$ are periodic with period $2\pi$, so the space over we integrate is not "physical dimensions" but those two momenta, and they actually are a local coordinates (the rectangle they parametrize is actually glued into a torus). This torus is called "Brillouin zone".
$$
k_x, k_y \in [0, 2\pi).
$$
For each energy band, we define the Berry connection $\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k})$ in terms of the Bloch eigenstates $\vert u(\mathbf{k}) \rangle$ as
$$
\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k}) = i \langle u(\mathbf{k}) \vert \nabla_{\mathbf{k}} \vert u(\mathbf{k}) \rangle.
$$
The Berry curvature $\Omega(\mathbf{k})$ is then given by the curl of the Berry connection:
$$
\Omega(\mathbf{k}) = \nabla_{\mathbf{k}} \times \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{k}).
$$
The Chern number $C$ for a given band is defined as the integral of the Berry curvature over the Brillouin zone (the torus $\mathbb{T}^2$):
$$
C = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{T}^2} \Omega(\mathbf{k}) \, d^2\mathbf{k}.
$$
In terms of $k_x$ and $k_y$, this becomes
$$
C = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \Omega(k_x, k_y) \, dk_x \, dk_y.
$$
The Chern number is proportional to "Hall conductivity"  of that band in the 2D crystal. The connection is via "TKNN" equation.

Thank you. Is this torus one integrates over naturally a submanifold of some bigger space?

I would say: not really. It is really  integral over a square plus "periodic boundary conditions" - you may realize this as a closed manifold in R^3 (a torus), but this R^3 does not come up naturally in any way.  This forus is a domain for "functions periodic in X and Y direction with period 2pi".

Thanks. So it seems we're not integrating a 2-form defined in a >2 dimensional space.

Phase space is an example of an abstract space that is not the physical space. Standard notation uses $p_i$ and $q_i$ as "canonical" coordinates, where the $p$ represents momenta and $q$ represents positions. Phase space has a famous two-form $\omega$, called the symplectic form. It is closed, but typically not exact. When you integrate $\omega$ over a surface in phase space, you can use Stoke's Theorem to equate this flux with the "action" $A(\gamma)$ as calculated by a line integral around the bounding curve $\gamma$.
Needless to say, symplectic geometry plays an important role in Hamiltonian mechanics.

Thanks! Some questions: did you really mean typically „not“ exact? If it is not exact, how would you apply Stokes? (Indeed, if we're talking about the cotangent space of some state space, the canonical symplectic form is exact, being the differential of the Liouville one form). I've forgotten what physicists call the action in symplectic geometry, but wouldn’t it involve a Hamiltonian function, which does not appear in you answer? And what physical meaning does that surface we integrate over have? (Put differently, why would a physicist choose a surface and integrate the symplectic form?)

@MichaelBächtold Maybe the first two pages of this paper by Dusa McDuff will be enlightening. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/24060234.pdf

Sorry, for the forum-y talky-ness, but giving what I can:

I would not too quickly dismiss the value in physical examples. Line and surface integrals are already sort of mysterious and abstract enough to begin with versus garden variety integrals.  So maybe nice to do them with physical examples (like flux of neutrons through the reactor sides).

Inspired by Steve, perhaps something in hysteresis magnetism?


https://www.nde-ed.org/Physics/Magnetism/HysteresisLoop.xhtml
I barely understand third semester calc itself, so can't give you the problem...but it sort of smells analogous to Steve's diagrams.
By the way, this is a practical and intuitive "example" of a non conservative field.  What goes up must come down, but not really to the same place, if there is hysteresis.  If ya get me.  I think about this physical example a lot when contemplating non reversible phenomena in social sciences.
P.s. I like Steve's comments.  Although I remember a lot of time, learning thermodynamic cycles (Carnot, Rankine, Otto, Diesel, Brayton, refrigeration, etc.) and staring at these diagrams and not doing any line or surface integrals...more just understanding the change in state of the fluid as it went from point to point and what that corresponded to within the machine physically (e.g. nozzle).

Thanks for the pointer to the hysteresis example. I will need time to look into it, but it does indeed smell like a one form integrated along a path.

Yeah, there is definitely path dependency.  And I think it sort of makes intuitive sense, if you think of ferromagnets and the little vectors inside that are "sticky".  ;)
